# System.Net.Security not found when sending mail from UWP application

Tags: c#, email, uwp, mailkit

I am trying to send an e-mail from my UWP application, and this is the error I am recieving:

> $exception    {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified. File name: 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
>   App1.glavnookno.d__10.MoveNext()} System.IO.FileNotFoundException

This is my code:

```
    try
        {
            //From Address
            string FromAddress = "rene.vucko@gmail.com";
            string FromAdressTitle = "Expenses to pay";
            //To Address  
            string ToAddress = "rene.vucko@gmail.com";
            string ToAdressTitle = "Microsoft ASP.NET Core";
            string Subject = "Hello World - Sending email using ASP.NET Core 1.1";
            string BodyContent = "ASP.NET Core was previously called ASP.NET 5. It was renamed in January 2016. It supports cross-platform frameworks ( Windows, Linux, Mac ) for building modern cloud-based internet-connected applications like IOT, web apps, and mobile back-end.";

            //Smtp Server  
            string SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
            //Smtp Port Number  
            int SmtpPortNumber = 587;

            var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
            mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromAdressTitle, FromAddress));
            mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(ToAdressTitle, ToAddress));
            mimeMessage.Subject = Subject;
            mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = BodyContent

            };

            using (var client2 = new SmtpClient())
            {

                client2.Connect(SmtpServer, SmtpPortNumber, false);
                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication  
                // Error 5.5.1 Authentication   
                client2.Authenticate("rene.vucko@gmail.com", "y");
                client2.Send(mimeMessage);
                Console.WriteLine("The mail has been sent successfully !!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                client2.Disconnect(true);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

I have less secure apps enabled, and I don't have two-step authentication. I am using the NUGET "MailKit" to send these mails, because I can't add the reference to system.web.mail, because VS2017 says it doesn't exist in my system.

These are the ones I am using:

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit;
```

My error: [image]

Comment: Check your references.  Chances are that you have a nuget that is newer than what is actually being reffed.  I get this when using updated packages like ValueTuple in .net 4.6 winforms apps.  To solve it, I have to do a explicit binding overrides in the app.config

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Why are you not using the built-in library? Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email)

Comment: I mean the MailKit reference is in the references tab...

Comment: Are you getting this error in the UWP app, or it is just receiving the error from the server?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vBdnN

Comment: @averagejoex that pic doesn't really say who we are looking at.  If its the server, setup a binding redirect:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions   if its UWP, I'm not familiar with how they do it.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, but it throw authorization exception when I have not enabled  "Allow Unsafe application".

Comment: This is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App25.git) you could refer to.

Comment: You probably just need to add a reference to System.Net.Security in your project.

Comment: @jstedfast I have the same problem with a UWP project in VS 2017.  I've tried adding System.Net.Security (various different versions of it) but with no success.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @jstedfast If it helps I have uploaded a sample project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmgkjEjadrvTla1Wevv7yWGtKWhjcg

Answer (score 0):

Solved, used EAMail instead. This one just doesn't work for VS2017 I guess.